# Function for difference calculation between datetime (months)

Tags: php, datetime, difference

my goal is to calculate the number of months between two dates including the starting month.

I am using this function to calculate.

```
function number_months($date1, $date2){
    $begin = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1)));
    $end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2)));

    $diff = $end->diff($begin);
    return ($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m') + 1;
}
```

In most cases in works fine, but when the function parameters are for example:

```
$date1 = 2015-11-04 00:00:00
$date2 = 2017-02-01 00:00:00
```

Function returns:

```
15
```

Should be `16`. What am I missing? I did reseach here on Stackoverflow, have tried various implementations of provided code, but the problem still ocurs.

Thanks.

Comment: add one into the result it will be 16 then,.,

Comment: Why should it be 16? (`2015-11`; `2015-12`; `2016-01`; `2016-02`; `2016-03`; `2016-04`; `2016-05`; `2016-06`;  `2016-07`; `2016-08`; `2016-09`; `2016-10`; `2016-11`; `2016-12`;  `2017-01` is __15__ months)

Comment: And why `$begin = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1)));`? Why not simply `$begin = new DateTime($date1);`?

Comment: @MarkBaker 16 (+`2017-02`)

Comment: No!. `2017-02-01 00:00:00` is __not__ part of February 2017; it's the midnight transition from Jan 31st to Feb 1st... so you're making a bad assumption in the first place; second problem is that you're still 4 days short of 16 months... either change your start point to 1st November rather than the 4th, or change your end point to 4th February rather than 1st, or add 1 if start-day > end-day, or change your assumptions

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, i didnt realise this. The problem is that the user will set the start and end date of project. And I need to create a input for every month the project is going to be set. So i need number 16 in this case. But now i think i will be albe to fix my problem.

Comment: `DateTime::diff()` works in full units when it comes to years, months, etc; so unless you can identify when to add 1 (e.g. start-day > end-day), you'll need to manipulate the dates to ensure that the range has full months (e.g. perhaps by setting the startdate to 1st of the month)

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, now i realise where the problem is. I think can fix the issue now as you suggested by setting the startdate and enddate  to 1st of the month.

Comment: `DateTime::diff()` works in full units when it comes to years, months, etc; so unless you can identify when to add 1 (e.g. start-day > end-day), you'll need to manipulate the dates to ensure that the range has full months (e.g. perhaps by setting the startdate to 1st of the month) for the value used for the calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the user will set the start and end date of project. And I need to create a input for every month the project is going to be set. So i need number `16` in this case.

Thanks to comments i realised that `DateTime::diff()` works in full units when it comes to years, months and days.

I solved my problem by setting the start and end date to 1st of the month. So now my function returns number of months between two dates including starting and ending month.

```
function number_months($date1, $date2){
    $begin = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1)));
    $end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2)));

    $begin->modify('first day of this month')->setTime(12, 00);
    $end->modify('first day of this month')->setTime(12, 00);

    $diff = $end->diff($begin);
    return ($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m') + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
11-04 to 12-04 = 1 month.
12-04 to 01-04 = 1 month.
01-04 to 02-01 = 0 month.
Result diff->format('%m') = 2.
```

($diff->format('%y') * 12) + $diff->format('%m') + 1 = 1*12 + 2 + 1 = 15;
    It's true.